# Won't scroll up when I use this swiping listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if(window.location.pathname == '/'){
  var direc; //swipe direction var
  function detectswipe(el,func) {
    swipe_det = new Object();
    swipe_det.sX = 0; swipe_det.sY = 0; swipe_det.eX = 0; swipe_det.eY = 0;
    var min_x = 40;  //min x swipe for horizontal swipe
    var max_y = 60;  //max y difference for horizontal swipe
    direc = "";
    ele = document.getElementById(el);
    ele.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e){
      var t = e.touches[0];
      swipe_det.sX = t.screenX;
      swipe_det.sY = t.screenY;
    },false);
    ele.addEventListener('touchmove',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var t = e.touches[0];
      swipe_det.eX = t.screenX;
      swipe_det.eY = t.screenY;
    },false);
    ele.addEventListener('touchend',function(e){
      //horizontal detection
      if ((((swipe_det.eX - min_x > swipe_det.sX) || (swipe_det.eX + min_x < swipe_det.sX)) && ((swipe_det.eY < swipe_det.sY + max_y) && (swipe_det.sY > swipe_det.eY - max_y) && (swipe_det.eX > 0)))) {
        if(swipe_det.eX > swipe_det.sX) direc = "r";
        else direc = "l";
      }

      if (direc != "") {
        if(typeof func == 'function') func(el,direc);
      }
      direc = "";
      swipe_det.sX = 0; swipe_det.sY = 0; swipe_det.eX = 0; swipe_det.eY = 0;
    },false);
  }

  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 5500); //keeps the slideshow moving
```

I can't get the page to scroll up or down with swiping with this function. It's supposed to be a left-right swipe detection. It obviously still scrolls when it's not listening for a touch/swipe. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I should mention I can't scroll with swiping ONLY when I touch the element selected. Any other place it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's very simple but it might help. https://jsfiddle.net/kyb3Lkqd/

```
var startingLocation = {x: 0, y:0};

$(document).on("touchstart", "#swp", function(e){
    console.log(e);
  startingLocation = {
    x: e.touches[0].clientX,
    y: e.touches[0].clientY
  };
});

$(document).on("touchmove", "#swp", function(e){
    console.log(e, e.touches[0].clientX, e.touches[0].clientY);
  if (startingLocation.x < e.touches[0].clientX){
     console.log('swiping right!');
  } else if (startingLocation.x > e.touches[0].clientX){
     console.log('swiping left!');
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually JUST got it working--was about to post the solution. It's so dead simple. I have e.preventDefault() in there--which stops the default action from being taken. In my case, I don't need that to be here (because of overflow prevention). It works beautifully now!

Answer (score 0):

It's incredibly simple; I'm almost embarrassed I didn't see it there in the beginning. In the original I had e.preventDefault(); to disable horizontal scrolling when the element was swiped. I don't need that anymore (I think) because I have overflow: hidden enable; which make that line redundant. Removing that makes it work flawlessly.